# Google App Script: Delay in success callback of google.script.run

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am calling the following server-side function using `google.script.run` from my client application.

**Google App Script**

```
function serverSideFunc(){
 console.time("serverSideFunc");
 try {
    console.time("Get range");
    let range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName(namedRange);
    console.timeEnd("Get range");
    if (range != null) {
        console.time("getNumRows");
        let rowCount = range.getNumRows();
        console.timeEnd("getNumRows");
        console.time("getValues");
        let multiArray = range.getValues();
        console.timeEnd("getValues");
        console.time("processCells");
        let array = [];
        for (var rCnt = 1; rCnt < rowCount; rCnt++) {
            let dataRow = {};
            for (var cCnt = 0; cCnt < multiArray[rCnt].length; cCnt++) {
                //processing the value
            }
        }
        console.timeEnd("processCells"); 
        return array;
    } else
        return null;
 } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex);
 }
 finally{
  console.timeEnd("serverSideFunc");
 }
}
```

Total execution time of above function is **160** milliseconds

**Client application**

```
function clientSideFunc(){
   console.time("Time taken for clientSideFunc");
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function (result) {
      console.timeEnd("Time taken for clientSideFunc")
    })
    .withFailureHandler(reject)
    .serverSideFunc);
}
```

The success callback is called after **1730** milliseconds. Hence, if the total execution time of `serverSideFunc` is 160 milliseconds, then why did it take **1,570** milliseconds more to invoke the success callback.

**Edit**

[image: Execution logs]

Any help or suggestion would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Provide Execution times screenshot? It should say whether serverfunc really took 1.7s? Also it might just be a static overhead of 1.5s..

Comment: @TheMaster, please check the screenshot. What is a static overhead?

Comment: Extras that can't be avoided like getting all the functions from server , executing other  injected client code, your browser speed, cpu, processor speed, os used, network delay/ping, bandwidth etc - static overhead. Anyway, your screenshot shows total time of 1.027s... right? So the overhead is only 700ms?

Comment: @TheMaster, Yes it shows 1.027s but the duration logged during execution is 160ms. Why is there a difference over there as well? I am using `console.time('label')` to log the timings. 
Anyway, isn't the overhead of 700ms is too high? I am using the system having high CPU and processor speed, network bandwidth is also around 35 Mbps.

Comment: See the network tab in dev tools. That should show delays. Could you show your serverside function? 160ms is for a specific process and not the whole function.

Comment: @TheMaster, I've included `serverSideFunc` function in the post.

Comment: Are there any globals?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227585/discussion-between-jayakrishnan-and-themaster).

Comment: I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug, you can click on the star next to the issue number to receive updates and to give more priority to the [report](https://issuetracker.google.com/177943054).